# Convert horizontal slick slider in Shopify to display vertically

Tags: slider, shopify, thumbnails, slick.js

I'm using the Debut theme in Shopify, which use a slick slider for the product thumbnail images.  It's currently display horizontally under the main big image. However, I want it to display vertically on the side of the main image.

I was able to move it to the side with redoing my grid. Then I went into the js section and added this:

```
vertical: true,
verticalSwiping: true,
```

However, that didn't do anything. I'm not sure what else I'm missing.

Here is what my page currently look like: [current look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ga0uQ.jpg)

Thank you,
Val